# visual studio solution migration from 2017 to 2019

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I have visual studio 2017 and 2019 in my machine , code written in 2017 . Now if i double click the solution of 2017 i want to open the solution in 2019 . Please provide the steps .

Comment: What kind of problems do you encounter when you open the code in VS2019?

Comment: Couldn't you right click the solution file, Select Visual Studio 2019 and before you press the OK button you make sure that you click the check box saying always open this type of file with this application?